# CheckBox Input Validation in Django

Tags: django, validation, checkbox

I want to add a checkbox to my registration field for terms&use. How can I write a clean method to validate this.

I have written a clean method where I want to be sure that I'm catching checkbox value correctly:

```
 def clean_terms(self):
         if self.cleaned_data["terms"] == u'on':
             raise forms.ValidationError(
                 "You have to accept terms&conditions to complete registration"
             )
```

As a result when I fill my registration form and post it, it gives me this validation error :

**Terms & Conditions: Select a valid choice. on is not one of the available choices.**

So how can I understand that a checkbox is checked and how to correctly implement a term&use checkbox ?

My checkbox field :

```
 terms = forms.ChoiceField(
     label="Terms&Conditions",
     widget=forms.CheckboxInput()
 )
```

Comment: Maybe you should show us how you're defining the checkbox in the first place?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't use a `ChoiceField` for a single checkbox. Use a [`BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield).

```
terms = forms.BooleanField(
    error_messages={'required': 'You must accept the terms and conditions'},
    label="Terms&Conditions"
)
```

You don't even need a `clean_` method.